# Uniform convergence of the series $\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{ne^{-nx}}{1+n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I'm triying to prove the uniform convergence of the series $$\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{ne^{-nx}}{1+n^2}$$ for $x\in (0,\infty)$, I tried to use the M-test many times, but only can acomplish this for $x\in[a,\infty)$, $a>0$. Can be an error in the exercise?

Comment: What kind of convergence are you trying to prove? If you only want to prove pointwise convergence, you're done.

Comment: @Ernesto if $x\in (0, +\infty)$, there exists some $0<a<x$ such that $x \in [a,+\infty)$.

Comment: Uniform convergence, in the Interval $(0,\infty)$ for $x$, the Interval of convergence is the big problem

Comment: @PierreCarre but the convergence in the closed intervals containing i. another doesn't implies the convergence in the open Interval in general

Comment: @Ernesto, you did not specify if you were talking about uniform convergence or pointwise convergence...

Comment: @PierreCarre It was in the title, i edit the problem, sorry it's my first time posting a question.

Comment: @Ernesto, my bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the series was uniformly convergent on $(0,+\infty)$ then for each $\varepsilon>0$ there would be an $N$ such that
$$
 \sum\limits_{n = N}^\infty  \frac{ne^{ - nx} }{1 + n^2 }  < \varepsilon
$$
for all $x>0$. Note however, that for $N\geq 1$
with $x=1/N$,
$$
\sum\limits_{n = N}^\infty  {\frac{{ne^{ - n\frac{1}{N}} }}{{1 + n^2 }}}  > \sum\limits_{n = N}^{2N} {\frac{{ne^{ - n\frac{1}{N}} }}{{1 + n^2 }}}  > e^{ - 2} \sum\limits_{n = N}^{2N} {\frac{n}{{1 + n^2 }}}  > e^{ - 2} \frac{{2N^2 }}{{1 + (2N)^2 }} > 0.05.
$$
Thus, if $\varepsilon<0.05$, there cannot be such a positive $N$.

Comment: Many thanks!, i was thinking about this all the night.